# Regarding updating existing accound record based on conditions in related object

Tags: apex

I have account object and site object.Site object have Supplier__c which is lookup up of account..
If payment__priority__c field in site object is 1 then Payment_priority_group_c field in account object should update to 1.I am writing script in anonymous code to update the existing records.

```java
List <Site__c> siteList = [SELECT Id, Payment_Priority__c, Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c, Supplier__r.S360Organization_registered_for_MSME_Act__c, Supplier__r.Name FROM Site__c
WHERE Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c = null AND Supplier__r.Name != NULL LIMIT 100];

List <Site__c> siteListToUpdate = new List <Site__c>();
for(Site__c s : siteList){
    if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 99 || s.Payment_Priority__c == Null ){
        s.Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c = '10';
    }else if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 1 || s.Supplier__r.S360Organization_registered_for_MSME_Act__c == 'Yes'){
        s.Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c = '1';
    }

    siteListToUpdate.add(s);
}

Update siteListToUpdate;
```

I tried this but still records not getting updated..can u help whats wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, it's not very clear what you're trying to do. Please rephrase your question. Also, this site isn't a place to get your work done for you for free. The expectation is that you've made an honest attempt, that you'll share that attempt with us, and that you will point to a narrow and specific thing that you're having trouble with. If you're getting any error messages, you should also include them _verbatim_ (don't try to shorten the error _at all_). [Edit] your question to add those details.

Comment: Also, if you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

DML cannot perform work on related records. If you're updating a list of `Site__c`, then it's only the changes made to `Site__c` records that get saved.

Since you want to update the related `Account` records, you need to build a collection of `Account`s and perform DML on that instead.

```java
List <Site__c> siteList = [SELECT Id, Payment_Priority__c, Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c, Supplier__r.S360Organization_registered_for_MSME_Act__c, Supplier__r.Name 
                           FROM Site__c
                           WHERE Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c = null AND Supplier__r.Name != NULL LIMIT 100];

// You'll get a "duplicate id in list" error if you have a List with the
//   same Account put into it twice.
// That's a concern because there can be multiple Sites that point to a single Account
// Using a map helps avoid that issue
Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(Site__c s : siteList){
    // The "__r" version of the relationship field is a fully-fledged SObject
    // This isn't necessary, but I find it helpful
    Account supplier = s.Supplier__r;

    if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 99 || s.Payment_Priority__c == Null ){
        supplier.Payment_Priority_Group__c = '10';
    }else if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 1 || s.Supplier__r.S360Organization_registered_for_MSME_Act__c == 'Yes'){
        supplier.Payment_Priority_Group__c = '1';
    }

    // If the key (i.e. supplier.Id) already exists in the map
    //   then calling .put() overwrites the value stored in the map
    // Because of that, the map will never contain duplicates
    //accountsMap.put(supplier.Id, supplier);
}

// DML only works on lists and single records, not maps
// So we need to get a list from our map, which is what .values() does
update accountsMap.values();
```

Now, it's not clear that *that* code will do what you want, but it should at least get you going in the right direction. You may or may not need to additionally query for `Supplier__r.Id`.

One thing I could see that may be an issue is *what priority group should get used if there are multiple `Site__c`s for a single `Account`?* There's not enough information in your question to provide any guidance on that. If it is a concern, then maybe checking if `accountsMap` already contains the Account you'd be working on (using `.containsKey()`) could help with that.